# Don't get the output of value of "P"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation and returns the result:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x=3;
var y=5;
function myFunction(){
  return x+y;
}
document.getElementById(demo).innerHTML = myFunction();
</script>
```

**Don't get the value of "P"
getting a debugging error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"**

Comment: `.getElementById(demo)`, here `demo` should be in quotes `"demo"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var x=3;
var y=5;
function myFunction(){
  return x+y;
}
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
demo.innerHTML = myFunction();
```

```html
<p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation and returns the result:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put " " or ' ' or `` around the ID you're trying to reference in the line document.getElementById(demo).innerHTML

without quotes you are referencing a variable which is not defined so it returns null. when you put quotes around it you're referencing "demo" from your HTML so this line should be and it will work.

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x=3;
var y=5;
function myFunction(){
  return x+y;
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction();
</script>
```